# How do I create a build configuration in Android Studio which executes a console command?

Tags: android-studio

I want to create a build configuration in android studio which runs a console command and nothing else. I also have another android build configuration which I don't want to change.

I've searched on the internet and haven't found any answers as to how an "empty" build configuration could be made.

I found the "Compound" build template, but that doesn't allow me to add "Before launch" configurations.

Is there any way of creating such a build configuration, which just executes a shell/console command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `Bash` Run Configuration in Android Studio. Edit the Run/Debug Configurations, press the add (`+`) button and select `Bash`:

[image: Add new bash configuration]

And then fill in the details similar to below:

[image: Bash Run Configuration]

Sample output below when selected and run in Android Studio:

[image: Sample output of Bash Run Configuration]